# Prove that ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not factorial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

> Prove that ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]=\{a+b\sqrt{-5}:a,b\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\}$ is not factorial.

I know that two representations of an irreducible element should be found that are not associated. Could you please help?

Comment: Is this homework? It sounds unnatural to ask a question that starts as a command "Prove that..", so it sounds like a textbook problem.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Consider
$
3^2 = 9 = (2+\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5})
$

Comment: But there is also some work after this.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, it's a hint to get started.

Comment: It's a right hint! +1

Comment: I showed that $3$ and $(2+\sqrt{-5})$ or $(2-\sqrt{-5})$ are not associated. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ArmenGabrielyan, you need also to prove that they are irreducible.

Comment: @Ihf Yes, I have also shown that they are irreducible.